# Docker ADD command produces 'cannot find the file' error

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, microservices, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to move my few microservices to a docker containers using docker-compose project type from Visual Studio.

I also have Service Fabric project so I have to install Service Fabric SDK into my docker containers.

That's what I do to achieve this (my dockerfile(s)):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

...

WORKDIR /temp

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe /temp #C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

...
```

The rest code doesn't matter since it crashes on line with ADD command.
The error from Output after I run this via Ctrl+F5:

```
3>Step 4/11 : ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe /temp
3>Service 'bmt.microservices.snowforecastcenter' failed to build: ADD failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder567273413\temp: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and what does it mean 'system cannot find the file' since I simply load the file from the internet and place it into my newly created \temp folder (the link is valid, I checked).

Does anybody know what this might be related to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've accidentally fixed the problem by moving comment to next line.

From this:

```
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe /temp #C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
```

To this:

```
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe /temp
#C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
```

Then I red on official site (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/from) that you cannot have inline comments since they are treated as arguments:

> Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment, unless the line is a valid parser directive. A # marker anywhere else in a line is treated as an argument.

I hope this will help other people who are new in Docker.